# How to disable Windows Server 2003 terminal server PIN login without losing smart card support?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, terminal-server, smartcard, windows-terminal-services

The users of a Windows Server 2003 terminal server should be able to use their national identity card (a smart card) inside the terminal session. This requires the Remote Desktop Connection's [x] Smart Cards checkbox to be checked.

Unfortunately (for us), when they have their card in the reader and connect using Remote Desktop and that checkbox is checked (so that they can use the card inside the terminal session), they are "greeted" with PIN prompt instead of username and password prompt.

They can click Cancel or press Esc every time and log in with username and password but is it possible to get rid of that PIN prompt without losing smart card support inside the terminal session (so that they can still authenticate themselves in a browser inside the terminal session)?